# X64 Windows Form Visual Style not 3D

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, managed-c++

In the following code (x64) the form visual style is not 3D despite using Fixed3D style. The resulting Window is shown.
I also used compiler directive to force using ComCtl32.dll Version 6, 
But no luck.

Any Ideas why I am not getting Visual Style 3D ?

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

#include <windows.h>

#using <System.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

public ref class Form1: public Form
{
public:
    Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void InitializeComponent()
    {
        Text = L"Form1";
        //Icon = gcnew System::Drawing::Icon(L"C:\\Form1.ico");
        StartPosition = FormStartPosition::WindowsDefaultLocation;

        ControlBox = true;
        MinimizeBox = true;
        MaximizeBox = false;

        Size = System::Drawing::Size(425, 308);

        FormBorderStyle = System::Windows::Forms::FormBorderStyle::Fixed3D;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The `FormBorderStyle` enumeration options are less visually distinctive in Windows when Aero Glass (or Windows 8 or later) are in use.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I changed windows theme to Windows Classic, Results are butter. But I still see other examples of Windows Forms on the internet where the visual style 3D has  better and more visually distinctive.

Comment: That 3D style is *so* 1990s.  Even the operating system gave up on it, hard to sell one when it looks 20+ years old.  The Aero theme overrides your dated preferences.  And usability most of all, Microsoft doesn't actually care that your UI looks from the stone age.  The borders are phat because it is necessary to give the user a shot at hitting them with a mouse.  Two pixels is not enough anymore on a high resolution monitor.